# Create COM components for Scripting using C# or VB.NET

Tags: c#, class, vbscript, com, interop

I would like to use my COM component in my VBScript as below.

```
Dim Object1

set Object1 = CreateObject("assembly.classname")

Object1(argument1, argument2,...).ChildObject(arg1,arg2,...).Method (arg1,arg2,arg3)
```

How can I design a C# Class library for COM so that I can call my component as above in VBScript.

I can able to create C# component and export to COM and can use in VBScript for simple methods..like

```
Dim o: set o = Createobject("assembly.class"): msgbox o.method1(arg1)
```

But the challenges are below

a) The parent object accepts unknow number of arguments (params in c#)

b) The parent object is called by its name directly (It is not called like object.method or object.propery)

I have tried few ways below, but could not success because COM and .NET interoperability issue.

1. I tried to use overload constructors in C#, but COM does not support constructor with arguments
2. I tried with overloaded methods, but COM does not support overloaded function with param array.
3. I tried to create a default property with arguments, but it also does not support paramarray.

Can we create C++ Component (non COM) in c#.NET and use it.
How can I design my class , collection of classes or array of classes or any other design to achieve the above style call from VBScript.
Any help would be appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Param arrays are a .NET feature, not a COM feature and not a VBScript feature.  You can't make this work.   Only an object[] argument is an option but certainly doesn't give you the vbs syntax you like.

Comment: Unfortunately, no way to use VBS/VBA paramarry (to declare MIDL attribute vararg).  Probably, the reason, that VBS/VBA  passes paramarray parameters (actually 1 parameter, of course) by reference. You can wrap your argumants into array on vbs side
call o.method(array(1,"2",3.0,somethingelse)). Just declare marshaling as follows [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_VARIANT )]
object [] foo